# How to redirect browser to new version number (directory) in URL in IIS-8 web.config?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I've tried using this web.config (IIS-8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Old version to new" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^help\.mysite\.com\/1\.2\/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://help.mysite.com/1.3/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This config generates 500 errors when trying to load any part of the site.

I want to update only the version number in the URL so everyone can continue to the content they were trying to access, just with the newer version. A full link might be:
http://help.mysite.com/1.2/Content/Widgets/installingWidgets.htm

Ideally, when the server starts to serve that page, it instead applies the redirect rule and the client ends up with:

http://help.mysite.com/1.3/Content/Widgets/installingWidgets.htm (along with any query strings that might have been present in the original request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to do as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect 1.2 to 1.3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^1\.2/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="1.3/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tested this and it does do a permanent (301) redirect and preserve the query string.

```
GET http://localhost/1.2/a/b?c=d&e=f HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost


HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://localhost/1.3/a/b?c=d&e=f
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 20:25:11 GMT
Content-Length: 159

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://localhost/1.3/a/b?c=d&amp;e=f">here</a></body>
```

The nice thing about using the `<match>` tag is that the input url will consist of everything to the right of the [application path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx), so this will work even if the help site is located in a virtual directory, for example, on a developer's machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this completely from memory, so I apologize if it's not 100% correct. I'm more than happy to discuss in the comments.

First, we don't need a `<match/>` statement since we're using conditions.

Second, matching against HTTP_HOST to find the matching "1.2" URL is incorrect. HTTP_HOST only contains the host portion of the URI, i.e., help.mysite.com. Instead, we need to match against REQUEST_URI, and we likely need the pattern `^/1\.2\/(.*)`.

The action you've written appears to be correct.

Give this a shot and see what happens.

```
<rule name="Old version to new" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/1\.2\/(.*)" />
    </conditions>

    <action type="Redirect" url="http://help.mysite.com/1.3/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```